# DLL not found error using uFllex in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll

I have bought, downloaded and then installed [uFlex](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/uflex-59843) for Unity. The install seemed to go without any errors, but when I try to run any of the example scenes I get lots of errors. The first and most serious sounding of which is:

```
DllNotFoundException: flexRelease_x64
uFlex.FlexSolver.Start () (at Assets/uFlex/Scripts/Solver/FlexSolver.cs:102)
```

Also the scenes don't seem to run/work. Have tried googling to see if it's a common error but that didn't show up anything. Tried finding the missing DLL but not sure where to put it, or whether it's platform/version specific?

1. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this
2. Anyone else have similar issues?
3. Not sure if it's relevant but I'm running Unity Version 2017.2.ob11 Personal, and my OS is Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS. I have windows installed as well - is switching to running Unity under Windows likely to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't and shouldn't work on Linux at this point.

Read the requirement from the plugin page:

> - NVidia GPU with at least CUDA 3.0 compute capability
> - Windows 64 bit (Win 32bit experimental, Android and Linux support planned)

The support is currently for Windows. You get the exception because the dll for Linux has not been provided. It can't load Windows dll on Linux. If the native side (C++) of the plugin is open-source, you can compile it for Linux and include it in your project then it should work. Since it's not, your only option at this moment is to switch to Windows.

Comment: Thanks.... if in doubt read the manual! Slightly irritating that it doesn't check for OS and flag incompatibility explicitly, but I should have read the requirements anyway.

Comment: Yeah but a really good and expensive plugin like that should have been able to handle this by displaying a log that shows that the plugin is not supported on the platform yet. That would have been more helpful and can easily be done with `Application.platform` or unity's macro `UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN **/** UNITY_EDITOR_WIN`.